# Set of injective mappings from an ordinal to a certain set is indeed a set

Tags: set-theory

I am working through the Hodges paper (1979) where he proves that Krull implies Zorn. He states that "Let $A$ be any set, and let $T$ be the set of injective maps $f:\alpha \rightarrow A$ with $\alpha$ an ordinal. (This is a set, by Hartogs' Theorem)". Hartogs' Theorem states that, for any set $A$, there exists an ordinal such that there is no injective function from $\alpha$ to $A$, but I fail to see how that implies that $T$ is a set.

Comment: Start with the fact that the collection of $\alpha$ for which there is such an $f$ is a set. Use this to show that the collection of all such $f$ (where $\alpha$ depends on $f$) is a set as well.

Comment: I proved that fact, but don't know how I should proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega(A)$ be the least ordinal such that there is no injective map from it to $A$. Then, $\omega(A)$ is the set of all the ordinals $\alpha$ such that there is an injective function $f:\alpha\to A$. And now it's a rather easy replacement: say, $\mathscr T:=\{A^X\,:\, X\in \omega(A)\}$ is a set by replacement and $T=\left\{f\in\bigcup\mathscr T\,:\, f\text{ injective}\right\}$.

Comment: Sorry, what is $A^X$?

Comment: The set of functions with domain $X$ and codomain $A$.